# ASP - Struggling with date format (in WHERE clause) when fetching records from MS Access DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

In the process of moving an existing (and previously working) site from Windows Server 2003 to Server 2008, jumping from IIS6 to IIS7, I have come across this oddity:

```
OpenSQL("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE apartment_id = '" & strApartment & "' AND BookDate = #" & SwitchDate(dDate) & "#")
```

**When run, the above SQL script only returns rows if there is no leading zero in the date. For example, it will return rows if the date is 10/01/2010. But it will not return rows if the date is 01/01/2010.** Instead I get this error:

> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

I'm not very familiar with ASP at all (in this instance running VB I believe, though it me be classic ASP - I'm not sure how you tell?). But this is a very simple request and I can't understand what is going on. I have tried removing the switchdate function (which removes all leading zeros), and playing with the syntax, all to no avail.

The Access DB holds the records in the format 01/01/2001.

Comment: Use a parameterized query, and let the work to figure out how to pass a correct formatted date value to the framework code.

Comment: What is `SwitchDate`?

Comment: Typically SQL uses mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss - what format does your SwitchDate() return, and what format is your SQL Database using? 01/01/2001 doesn't tell us if it's month/day/year or day/month/year.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the format is dd/mm/yyyy. I should have noted that! I will take a look at the switch statement, as being an ASP novice I wasn't sure if this was an inbuilt or custom function. But it makes more sense now based on the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that the ACE and Jet database engines treat ambiguous `#xx/yy/zzzz#` date literals as `mm/dd/yyyy` they also accept the unambiguous formats `yyyy-mm-dd` and `yyyy/mm/dd` so your best solution would be to update your `SwitchDate()` function to return one of those formats.

Comment: Just checked the SwitchDate function and it was returning mm/dd/yyyy. I have updated it to dd/mm/yyyy and it is now working. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Could it be because I set the locale to the UK - as this is a typical UK date format?

Comment: Good to hear that it's working, but `yyyy-mm-dd` is still the preferred choice. The most likely reason that the thing broke in the first place is that the servers had different "Short Date" formats defined in Windows' "Regional Settings" control panel. Using an unambiguous format could potentially save the next person some head-scratching if a similar situation arises in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gord. I tried updating to the suggested format but I'm getting the same error. This is a very old site too, and I suspect it won't be around too much longer, so I'm happy with the fix so far.